# Google Sheets Data Feed has extra column headers in the JSON

Tags: google-sheets, json

I have a client who is using Google Sheets as a data feed. When using the correctly structured URL for the sheet, I see blank columns in the target table. When I look in the code inspector, I see gsx column header properties that are not an exact match with the column headers.

For example, in the table I am looking at, the first column is name "Case Number". This column is blank in the target table even though it should be populated with case numbers. When I look in the code inspector (Google Chrome), I open up the first row of data in the JSON object and see a key named 'gsx$casenumber'. This key has the property 'undefined'.

In the Google Sheet itself, the case numbers fill this column.

What's odd is that, even with a fresh spreadsheet, the 'gsx$casenumber' key has a property $t of 'undefined'. The column header in the Google Sheet is 'Case Number'.

The next key in the Google Sheet JSON object is'gsx$caseprefixtoeachcaseisd202cv'. This is the key in which the $t properties have the case numbers I should be able to see in the rendered table. This is happening in other columns, too.

Is there a way to either remove the first google sheet key in the JSON, or bind the key with the case numbers to the corresponding column header in the rendered table?

Any input or help with this would be greatly appreciated.

[image: screenshot with detail of rendered table and JSON object]

Comment: Welcome. How are you getting the Google Sheets data feed? What means "correctly structured URL for the sheet"?

Comment: Hi Ruben -- I am using the https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/GOOGLESHEETID/2/public/values?alt=json as a data feed. I'm bringing it in with 'data.feed.entry', which works. What I can't figure out is how Google Sheets is creating additional property keys or how they are being brought into new spreadsheets.

Comment: I think that the URL is result of publishing to the web as JSON the related spreadsheet. AFAIK this feature doesn't offers customization options so IMHO your best bet is to parse the resulting JSON and maybe convert it to something that fit your needs. Questions about parsing/converting JSON  are off-topic on this site  (unless you use a web application to do that).